# Why Tomcat library folder WEB-INF/lib is empty?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

I deploy my Maven webapp using Spring MVC in Eclipse Tomcat. Everything works OK for quite a week. Suddenly, today I modify a properties file, rebuild and redeploy the webapp. There's a class not found error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener
```

Look at publish folder (tmp0) of Tomcat server plugin located in workspace folder, there are no jars in WEB-INF/lib any more. I don't know why? I have rebuilt/deployed it many times today, and have found no problem.

Could someone give an advice? Thanks very much.

EDIT:

I can't find a right solution for this problem, though I temporarily bypass it by removing the web app from Tomcat Server, do a clean up, then add it back again.

Comment: What are the changes you have made in properties file, can you show?

Comment: I added an entry in classpath:application.properties. I argue that's not problem because before that I have had add another and no problem occurs. `casClient.afterLogoutUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8084%2Fmyweb`

Comment: may be .class file broken or problem in jar

Comment: I have also the same problem. web-inf/lib folder is empty. m2e-wtp version is 0.16. m2e version is 1.0.200. Cleaning glassfish and redeploying does not work for me.

Comment: Be make sure that you remove web app before doing a clean up. That's the right way for my case with Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have m2eclipse WTP integration installed? There are few things you could try:

- Maven->Update project configuration
- Close and open project
- Remove project from Tomcat instance in WTP, Clean up and add it back.

Depending on your version of Eclipse and m2eclipse/m2e and WTP the integration could be finicky sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I have m2eclipse WTP integration installed. I find this behavior mystery as well. I sometimes encounter this, and the only solutions is creating a new server.

Answer (score 0):

- Is this option enabled? ProjectName (right-click) > Maven > Enable Dependency Management
  You should have in ProjectName > properties > Java Build Path > Libraries an item called Maven2 Dependencies
- Is your M2_REPO variable set? Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables

If it's all ok, check the war that Maven is creating to see if the libs are there and in the correct folder (web-inf\libs). Check the maven output when generating the war.

Comment: Certainly Maven2 Dependencies and M2_REPO variable are properly set. I check in folder WEB-INF/lib in war file generated by running mvn in command line, all necessary jars are there.